# A star algorithm, but in four directions only

Tags: c, algorithm, path-finding

I've been reading about path-finding algorithms and I'm currently looking for one that works just like the A* but where the agent cannot move diagonally. Do the nodes still expand diagonally or is it some other way? Perhaps it's not related to A* at all? Also please consider the following image where it shows that the triangle is our agent, the brown rectangle is an obstacle between the grid squares and the arrow is just to make it clear that you can still walk through squares that have obstacles on their "borders", when not face to face to that obstacle. What kind of algorithm would you advise me as a base to a path-finding problem with these characteristics? Forgive me if something like this was posted already, I couldn't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A* is a search algorithm in a graph, given a starting location and a set of target nodes, it finds a path - based on the graph's vertices and edges.

If you want your agent to be unable to move diagonally, all you need to do is design your graph such that there is no edge between diagonal vertices.

I assume you are using a `next:V->2^V` function to get all positions your agent can be next step. If it is the case, just make sure diagonals are not returned from this function.

Answer (score 2):

Just as amit said, A* is a search algorithm and can be applied to (almost) any search problem.

Any *search problem* can be described (or defined) with these parameters:

- starting state (position)
- transition function (if given any state **a**, what are states you can get in *one* step)
- end state (position)

Start and end state as well as transition function can be given explicitly or implicitly, e.g. when moving through a grid (like in your problem), next positions could be any neighbor (up, down, left, right + maybe diagonally) or there could be explicit info contained in one space.
End state could also be known before hand (e.g. state with coordinates **(x,y)**), or it could be defined by some characteristic of the state (e.g. if there are coins in the grid, end state could be any state with a coin).

Most common search algorithms are BFS, DFS, iterative-DFS (non-directed), hill-climbing, A* (directed). There are many [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) - look at the graphic on the right of the wiki page. Some of them are *complete* (meaning, an end state will *always* be found even in an infinite search space if it exists - BFS, A*), while some are not (DFS, hill-climbing). The other categorization is by algorithms *optimality*. Optimal searches will find the best possible solution, or the best possible path to it (BFS for non-weighted graphs, A*), while with others will find any acceptable solution or any possible path to the solution (BFS in weighted graphs). Usually, there's a trade-off between computational complexity, memory requirements and the simplicity of the implementation. Directed searches additionally *use some pre-known information about the end state* to direct a search (estimate of the end-state distance from any given state), while non-directed searches do not.

For example, if you know the coordinates of the start and end positions, directed search makes sense. If start position is in the upper left corner, and the end position is in the lower left corner, you prefer to search the states in the downward direction versus the states to the right. If your start position is in the middle of the board, end the end position in not explicit (defined by a characteristic), and can be *anywhere* in the board, directed search is not of much help.

Also, if your problem is not of great magnitude (e.g. search in a 100x100 board), there usually isn't a good reason to use directed search, BFS or other non-directed search algorithms will work fast enough and the speed-up gained by using more complex, directed searches is not significant.

Notice that *all of the search algorithms can work with any given transition function*.

So, **to conclude**. The type of algorithm you should use depends on your problem limitations:

- small search-space, no known info about the end state: *un-directed (BFS, DFS)*
- limited memory: *DFS, iterative-DFS*
- larger search-space + known information about the end state: *directed* (*A**, *hill-climbing*)
- no local extremes in the search space (e.g. no obstacles) or limited memory + known info about the end: *hill-climbing*
- there usually are many more limitations to be taken into account, and the search algorithms are just examples of algorithms that *might* be good in said situations (but also might not be, depending on additional limitations)

This is just a short overview of the search algorithms and just gives the general ideal. If you are uncertain about which algorithm is most suitable for your problem, you should read up on the characteristics and applications in more detail.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: **Hill climbing** is optimizing search algorithm, it only searches for a good solution - it **doesn't guarantee anything** about the resulting node [except it is local minima/maxima], and specifically - it is NOT path finding algorithm for a pre-defined target state, so it is used for a completely different purpose then A*. Also: BFS and DFS fails when it comes to weighted graphs. If you have weighted graph and you are not informed: Dijkstra/Bellman Ford is prefered over BFS/DFS - to ensure optimal solution.

Comment: I taught I said that when talking about complete searches, but I checked again and I made an error typing too fast - I've corrected it, now it says that DFS and hill-climbing (before it said, A*) are not guaranteed to find a (optimal) solution. TY. Also, since BFS is a *complete* search, it will find a correct solution in a weighted graph eventually. It might not be **appropriate** for such a problem (there are algos that solve it faster), but it would not fail. And DFS can fail in any infinite search-space without a control mechanism for visited states.

Comment: (1) hillclimbing - unlike the rest of algorithms you described is **not** path finding algorithm... it is not designed to find a "target state" at all, it is more state searching algorithm, and it does not fit the problem described by the OP (2) DFS can fail even if there is mechanism to prevent loops: if it encounters an infinite branch. (3) BFS is indeed complete, but it is not [optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Optimality) for weighted graphs, so the path returned by it - might not be optimal.

Comment: (*) I will clarify myself about hill climbing: hillclimbing in this problem will behave similar to greedy search [search for the smallest heuristic value, and follow it], assuming your heuristic function is not perfect, it will fail to find the optimal path - and in some cases might fail to find the target state at all!

Comment: A list of graph&tree search algorithms from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_search_algorithm) (not the best source in the world, but still). Hill-climbing is definitely NOT the right solution for the problem stated above (it **is** a greedy algorithm for graph searching), but it felt right to mention it in the overview of the techniques. DFS can fail in many cases, let's agree on that and not state all of them separately. Everything you said was correct. But, I can't write a complete overview of **all** search algos here - that takes several wiki articles :)

Comment: I agree you cannot write everything, but My comments were about specific points you mentioned/failed to mention [mentioning BFS should be used only for unweighted graphs for example] in your answer/comments - and I fixed your mistake, in order for you to: (1) learn, if you didn't know that already; (2) fix your answer - to prevent mistakes of future readers of your answer.

Comment: i'm going to go add a passage about optimal/non optimal search algorithms now

Comment: Hey penelope, thanks for your explanations, however I had already investigated some of these and for the purposes of the problem at hand your answer is broader. Amit's answer made me go "okay this is probably what I have to do really". However that doesn't mean your answer wasn't equally as helpful, I just have to choose one :) Thanks.